# Start and check name of window on virtual X display

Tags: python, xlib, xorg, xdotool

I'm writing a test on Ubuntu 18.04. I want to create a virtual display, start a window on it, and check the window name. In three separate shells I'm running:

```
Xvfb :4 -screen 0 1920x1080x24+32 -fbdir /var/tmp
```

then

```
DISPLAY=:4 xterm
```

then

```
DISPLAY=:4 xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname
```

That last command returns

```
XGetInputFocus returned the focused window of 1. This is likely a bug in the X server.
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x1
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

That error seems to come from [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/master/xdo.c#L1131):

```
int xdo_get_focused_window(const xdo_t *xdo, Window *window_ret) {
  int ret = 0;
  int unused_revert_ret;

  ret = XGetInputFocus(xdo->xdpy, window_ret, &unused_revert_ret);

  /* Xvfb with no window manager and given otherwise no input, with 
   * a single client, will return the current focused window as '1'
   * I think this is a bug, so let's alert the user. */
  if (*window_ret == 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, 
            "XGetInputFocus returned the focused window of %ld. "
            "This is likely a bug in the X server.\n", *window_ret);
  }
  return _is_success("XGetInputFocus", ret == 0, xdo);
}
```

I just want to do the minimal thing to get  a virtual display, start a window on it, and check the window name.

What should I do?

Comment: Start a WM such as `twm` on that X display. So that `xdotool` has some one to talk to.

Comment: @DanD. I tried running `DISPLAY=:4 twm` before `DISPLAY=:4 xterm` (in yet another shell). Now instead of returning an error message, `DISPLAY=:4 xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname` just hangs.

Comment: @DanD. It works with i3 though, thanks!